# ColdFusion MySQL Backup with DSN

Tags: coldfusion, mysql, dsn

I have ColdFusion (8) that hooks into a MySQL DB. It uses a DSN connection.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a backup of the DB? It's fairly hefty at around 10Gb so was wondering if there were any extra precautions I'd need to take to ensure it's successful i.e. prevent timeouts

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: I wouldn't use coldfusion to create a backup (if thats what you're asking), there are dedicated tools for such jobs.  I would look at a solution like http://www.navicat.com/

Comment: Unfortunately with the security on the server, I can't use it. It needs to be done via ColdFusion. I would need to get onto a VPN - which has been disabled!

Comment: Unless you add a process to your workflow that moves the backup to a different location, the backups will be useless if there is a total system failure. The backups will be lost with everything else.

Comment: I just want to make one backup - it's not for routine backups

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to test this currently, but theoretically you can use `<cfexecute>` to call the mysqldump utility on the database server.  This takes a `timeout=` parameter, so you can leave a nice long timeout on it.

the documentation for the mysqldump is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html i've not used it myself so can't advise on the correct parameters to use (which you would pass in to the `arguments=` parameters of the `cfexecute`.

Comment: Thanks - I've had a look but see nowhere obvious to pass the DSN information rather than username/password

Comment: You do not use a DSN with MySQLDump. It is an executable that comes with MySQL, completely separate from CF. That said, if you are on a shared server, it may not be an option. You would need appropriate access and permission to use `<cfexecute>` (often disabled for security reasons).